# Problems with paypal api in android

Tags: android, api, paypal

Hey Im trying to integrate Paypal MPL API in android but im having a lot of troubles...
I have done all of https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-accept-payments-android-app-using-mpl steps, but when i run my project i get this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalPayment

I have integrated the mpl.jar file in my project.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void initLibrary() {
      PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
      if (pp == null) { 
        pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_NONE);
        pp.setLanguage("en_US");
        pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);
        pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
      }
    }
private void showPayPalButton() {
      PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
      final CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton;
      launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
      launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
      params.bottomMargin = 10;
      launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
      launchPayPalButton.setId(10);
      ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
      ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    }
public void PayPalButtonClick(View arg0) {
      PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
      payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
      payment.setRecipient("nons3nsedevelopment@gmail.com");
      payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(10));
      payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
      PayPalInvoiceData invoice = new PayPalInvoiceData();
      invoice.setTax(new BigDecimal(5));
    }
public void PayPalActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      switch (resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
          String payKey = intent.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
          //this.paymentSucceeded(payKey);
          break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
          //this.paymentCanceled();
          break;
        case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
          String errorID = intent.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
          String errorMessage = intent.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
          //this.paymentFailed(errorID, errorMessage);
      }
    }
```

I dont find errors over here...

Answer (score 0):

MPL is in the process of being deprecated. It's recommended that you use the new [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) instead.

Comment: I'm having alot of troubles with the android integration. I'm Non-US citizen so i'm using classic apis but can't find an appropriate tutorial or solution. Can you please Advise :)

Comment: That error indicates that your classpath doesn't include the jar. Make sure that mpl.jar is in your project's 'libs' directory. That should be sufficient but if not, you might need to add it to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

Copy PayPal latest SDK jar file Paste libs folder in your project, then right click the jar file add to build path,

try below code.

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
 private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AVLi6hDi_hTrqeVnADnRQ6jOF8VIj1b8nWbRof2ciyWhOKaOxnJr6wJKf7mi"; //"credential from developer.paypal.com";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
    .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
    .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
    // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
    .merchantName("Hipster Store")
    .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
    .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);

        }
 public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
     PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
}

 private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String environment) {
        return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(100)), "USD", "Android Mobile",
                environment);
    }
```

}